# How to get a list of lists from a dictionary of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, converters

I want to convert a dictionary of dictionaries to a list of lists. The format of the dictionary is:

```
{0: {’apple’: 2, ’orange’: 5, ’banana’: 4}, 1: {'apple’: 2, ’orange’: 1, ’banana’: 7}}
```

Where the keys go from 0,1,2,3 etc... and the values of the keys inside the dictionary is the number of that fruit. I'm trying to make a list of lists that looks like:

```
 [[2, 5, 4], [2, 1, 7]]
```

Where each sublist is the original key (0,1,2,3 etc...). So if there are 4 dictionaries, then there are 4 sublists.

Id prefer with no fancy code and no imports. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the answers down there, it's almost like unordered dicts never existed... and of course the OP's dicts had their keys created in exactly the correct order, we all know that, right? They couldn't possibly have been created in any other order /s

Comment: There's no indication that order is important @Aran-Fey.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simple list comprehension with `values()`:

```
myDict = {0: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 5, 'banana': 4}, 1: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 7}}

arr = [list(d.values()) for d in myDict.values()]
#[[2, 5, 4], [2, 1, 7]]
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Is there a way to do this without list comprehension? As I am not familiar with it.

Comment: A list comprehension is the way to do this in python. The alternative is to make a list and in for loop and append each list to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {0: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 5, 'banana': 4}, 1: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 7}}


print([list(z.values()) for y,z in x.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x={0: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 5, 'banana': 4}, 1: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 7}}
lst=[]
lst1=[]
for key,iteam in x.items():
    for k,itm in iteam.items():
        lst.append(itm)
    print(lst)
    lst1.append(lst)
    lst=[]
```

no problem dear?